# Multiple Figures in Matplotlib - Nested Loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

First I want to generate a plot, colorized by how close the average data is to the goal. (the real program is a machine learning algorithm trying to learn weights). I want to generate a histogram for each data point in the final plot, but I can't seem to generate the plots independently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def generateData(goal):
    x=[_ for _ in range(20)]
    y=[10+np.random.exponential()*5 for _ in range(100)]
    return x,y

def drawHistogram(data,nBins):
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.hist(diffs,nBins)
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()

sweep=np.linspace(10,20,4)

for goal in sweep:
    for gw2 in sweep:

        diffs=[]

        for i in range(10):
            data=generateData(goal)
            diffs.append(goal-np.mean(data[1]))


        #generate plot
        plt.figure(1)
        clr=(abs(np.mean(diffs))/goal,0,0)
        plt.plot([goal], [gw2], marker="s", mew='1', ms='35', color=clr)

        drawHistogram(diffs,5) ##Comment this line out to see what the final graph should look like

plt.figure(1)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.figure(2)` creates a new figure. Is that desired or not?

Comment: As an example, if you would like to create a plot for each iteration of the loop, you could do: `for g, goal in enumerate(sweep): plt.figure(g+1)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes - I want to basically append to figure(1) and to create a histogram, figure(2), for each of those points.

Comment: The problem is when I run this code, when I call plt.draw() and plt.show() in drawHistogram(), it draws both figures instead of only the histogram. I only want to draw figure(1) at the end.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to exactly when a new plot needs to be generated? What do you mean by appending to `figure(1)`? FYI `plt.show()` will display all figures.

Comment: Is this what you want your plots to look like? https://imgur.com/a/evkAZ

Comment: @DavidOwens Ahh I understand, thank you. Correct me if i'm wrong, but what you did was call plt.show() at the end only. Actually, what I want to do is make a new histogram for each iteration, in which case I will need to create a new figure. It was confusing calling plt.show at every iteration, but calling it once at the end made me realize what's going on.

Comment: Yeah each time in `drawHistogram` where you say `plt.figure(2)` you are switching back to the same figure. You can just call `plt.figure()` with no params to generate a new histogram each time that `drawHistogram` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generates 17 individual histograms and 1 final figure with the red squares.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def generateData(goal):
    x=[_ for _ in range(20)]
    y=[10+np.random.exponential()*5 for _ in range(100)]
    return x,y

def drawHistogram(data,nBins):
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(diffs,nBins)

sweep=np.linspace(10,20,4)

for goal in sweep:
    for gw2 in sweep:

        diffs=[]

        for i in range(10):
            data=generateData(goal)
            diffs.append(goal-np.mean(data[1]))

        #generate plot
        plt.figure(1)
        clr=(abs(np.mean(diffs))/goal,0,0)
        plt.plot([goal], [gw2], marker="s", mew='1', ms='35', color=clr)

        drawHistogram(diffs,5) ##Comment this line out to see what the final graph should look like

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```